# Okay, so my code is compiled but the if/else statement is not working

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I think it might be due the switch statement.
Do I have make the both them switch statements for them to work out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class mylab

{
   public static void main(String[] args) 

   {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

       int month;
       int day;
       String season= "seasons";

       System.out.print("type a two digit month");
       System.out.print(" and day");
       month = in.nextInt();
       day = in.nextInt();

       String winter = " winter ";
       String summer = " summer";
       String spring = " spring";

       System.out.print(" Month="+ month +" Day= "+day);

       switch (month) {
           case 1:  
               month = 1; System.out.println(" Winter");
               break;
           case 2:  
               month = 2; System.out.println(" Winter");
               break;
           case 3:  
               month= 3;System.out.println(" Winter");
               break;
           case 4:
               month= 4;System.out.println(" Spring");
               break;
           case 5:  
               month = 5;System.out.println(" Spring");
               break;
           case 6:
               month = 6 ;System.out.println(" Spring");
               break;
           case 7: 
               month = 7 ;System.out.println(" Summer");
               break;
           case 8: 
               month = 8;System.out.println(" Summer");
               break;
           case 9:
               month = 9;System.out.println(" Summer");
               break;
           case 10:
               month = 10;System.out.println(" Fall");
               break;
           case 11: 
               month = 11;System.out.println(" Fall");
               break;
           case 12:
               month = 12;System.out.println(" Fall");
               break;
        }
```

**How , do I make this part work with the switch statement** 
the pseudo code for this portion is If month is divisible by 3 and day >= 21, If season is "Winter", season = "Spring",Else if season is "Spring", season = "Summer",Else if season is "Summer", season = "Fall"
 Else season = "Winter"

```
  if (month % 3 == 0 && day >= 21)  
  {
      if ( season.equals(winter) )  
          System.out.println(" Spring");   
      else if ( season.equals(spring) ) 
          System.out.println ( "Summer" );  
      else if ( season.equals(summer) ) 
          System.out.println ( " fall");
      else if ( season.equals(winter) ) 
          System.out.println( " winter");

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: That's not "pseudo-code", it's Java. It's source code in a programming language. Your question has nothing to do with IDEs, either. It helps you get answers more quickly if you actually use tags that apply to your question.

Comment: check your capitalisation and spaces. also, these assignments of month in the switch are redundant.

Comment: `season` is always the string "seasons". You never assign one of the values you are checking for to it so the equality checks always fail.

Comment: `switch(month) case 1: month = 1;` ... why?

Comment: @tvanfosson that's good enough for an answer :)

Comment: Instead of printing the season in your switch statement, assign the season string to the `season` variable. Also, remove the redundant month assignments in the switch statement.

Comment: Sorry, I am still a bit confused. This is 1st piece code I have written.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd probably write it (if I absolutely had to keep the switch and I didn't care to check user input):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class mylab {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int month, day;
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.print("Type a two digit month: ");
       month = in.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Type a two digit day: ");
       day = in.nextInt();

       System.out.print(" Month="+ month +" Day= "+day+" ");

       if(month%3==0 && day>=21) {
         month++;
         if(month>12) month=1;
       }
       switch (month) {
         case 1: case 2: case 3: System.out.println("Winter"); break;
         case 4: case 5: case 6: System.out.println("Spring"); break;
         case 7: case 8: case 9: System.out.println("Summer"); break;
         case 10: case 11: case 12: System.out.println("Fall"); break;
       }
   }
}
```